# Php : How to display just the month of current year (subtracted -1)

Tags: php

I need to open a pdf file which is in specific format like
**MPA_154278A_03_2013**

prifix **(MPA)** is same in every month 
middle component **(15427A)** can be any number+1 Alphabet in last and
Suffix is last month and current year **(_03_2013)**

I coded like this but cant able to get previous month number (_03)

```
<?php
$number=$_REQUEST['input']; // input for midle name of file
//checking for file exist
$file_name="pdf_files/MPA_".$number."_".date('m')."_".date('Y').".pdf"; // for file opening
//echo $file_name;
if(file_exists($file_name))
    echo $file_name;
else
    echo 0;
?>
```

Comment: Subtracted -1 is the same as added 1...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will get string **_03_2013** by this,

```
$date = date('_m_Y', strtotime(date('Y-m')." -1 month"));
```

So your filename will be generate like,

```
$file_name="pdf_files/MPA_".$number.$date.".pdf";
```

[CodeViper Demo.](http://codepad.viper-7.com/1fwPJV)

Comment: Thanks a lot dear very specific answer.

Comment: @SadiqueHassan - Glad to help you. Please don't forget to accept my answer by clicking the checkmark to the left of it.